# css margin: auto issue in footer

Tags: html, css, margin, footer, listitem

My problem is to split the space inside my footer bar in 3 part (each with same width)

```css
footer {
  width: 100%;
  /*breite: 100%*/
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: darkcyan;
  /*Hintergrundfarbe*/
  margin-bottom: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.footer-items {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  /*bringt alle Teile in eine Linie*/
  text-align: center;
  /*zentriert ganzen Text im footer*/
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-items">

  <div class="company-items">
    <h3 class="company">Company</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="text1.html">Text1</a></li>
      <li><a href="text2.html">Text2</a></li>
      <li><a href="text3.html">Text3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="social-items">
    <h3 class="social">Social</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Twitter</a></li>
      <li><a>Instagram</a></li>
      <li><a>Reddit</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="other-items">
    <h3 class="text">Text4</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a>other1</a></li>
      <li><a>other2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

If I try to do sth like `margin-left: 33%` for my 3 items in footer this is not gonna work.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `width: 33.33%` instead of `margin-left: 33%` and apply the class to each third of the footer. This will split the footer into 3 columns:

```css
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  /*breite: 100%*/
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: darkcyan;
  /*Hintergrundfarbe*/
  margin-bottom: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.footer-column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">

  <div class="footer-column">
    <h3 class="company">Company</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="text1.html">Text1</a></li>
      <li><a href="text2.html">Text2</a></li>
      <li><a href="text3.html">Text3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="footer-column">
    <h3 class="social">Social</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Twitter</a></li>
      <li><a>Instagram</a></li>
      <li><a>Reddit</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="footer-column">
    <h3 class="text">Text4</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a>other1</a></li>
      <li><a>other2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using flex properties of CSS and I have added snippet below. Please check :

```css
footer{
            width: 100%; /*breite: 100%*/
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            background-color: darkcyan; /*Hintergrundfarbe*/
            margin-bottom: 0;
            bottom: 0;
          }

          .footer-items{
            width: 80%;
            margin: auto;
            display: flex; /*bringt alle Teile in eine Linie*/
            text-align: center; /*zentriert ganzen Text im footer*/
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: flex-start;
          }

          .footer-items .company-items, .footer-items .social-items, .footer-items .other-items {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: left;
          }
```

```html
    <div class="footer-items">
        <div class="company-items">
          <h3 class="company">Company</h3>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="text1.html">Text1</a></li>
              <li><a href="text2.html">Text2</a></li>
              <li><a href="text3.html">Text3</a></li>
            </ul> 
        </div>

        <div class="social-items">
          <h3 class="social">Social</h3>
            <ul>
              <li><a>Twitter</a></li>
              <li><a>Instagram</a></li>
              <li><a>Reddit</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="other-items">
          <h3 class="text">Text4</h3>
            <ul>
              <li><a>other1</a></li>
              <li><a>other2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: By using this way, you don't need to specifically define width for child element. It will automatically manage.

Comment: that works nearly fine for me, but now the list items (ul li a) are not justified with the headers (company, social and text4). how can I make them left justifyed?

Comment: It's difficult to suggest anything before checking URL. Please provide any link so that I can check it and provide solution for it.

Comment: its not a real website, I just enjoy to learn it, so I dont have a URL.

Answer (score 0):

I see your `.footer-items` is `display: flex;`, you could make its nearest children grow evenly.

Look into the snippet. (Aslo you could remove `text-align: center;`)

```css
footer {
  width: 100%;
  /*breite: 100%*/
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: darkcyan;
  /*Hintergrundfarbe*/
  margin-bottom: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.footer-items {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  /*bringt alle Teile in eine Linie*/
  /*text-align: center;*/
  /*zentriert ganzen Text im footer*/
}

.footer-items > div {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-items">

  <div class="company-items">
    <h3 class="company">Company</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="text1.html">Text1</a></li>
      <li><a href="text2.html">Text2</a></li>
      <li><a href="text3.html">Text3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="social-items">
    <h3 class="social">Social</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Twitter</a></li>
      <li><a>Instagram</a></li>
      <li><a>Reddit</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="other-items">
    <h3 class="text">Text4</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a>other1</a></li>
      <li><a>other2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `display: grid` like so. You can define 3 columns for each of the footer items and give it a width of 1fr or 1 fraction `grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr;`. You can also define a grid gap for instead of margin.

Answer (score 0):

put the width of div elements 33.33% ((100%)/number of columns) and set 0px margin for right and left.

```css
footer {
  width: 100%;
  /*breite: 100%*/
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: darkcyan;
  /*Hintergrundfarbe*/
  margin-bottom: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.footer-items {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-right:0px;
  margin-left:0px;
  display: flex;
  /*bringt alle Teile in eine Linie*/
  text-align: center;
  /*zentriert ganzen Text im footer*/
}

.div-box{
  width:33.33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-items">

  <div class="company-items div-box">
    <h3 class="company">Company</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="text1.html">Text1</a></li>
      <li><a href="text2.html">Text2</a></li>
      <li><a href="text3.html">Text3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="social-items div-box">
    <h3 class="social">Social</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Twitter</a></li>
      <li><a>Instagram</a></li>
      <li><a>Reddit</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="other-items div-box">
    <h3 class="text">Text4</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a>other1</a></li>
      <li><a>other2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```